# Failed to encrypt the section "appSettings" using provider "MyProvider". Error message from the provider: Object already exists

Tags: encryption, iis-10, aspnet-regiis.exe

This question has been asked many times but the accepted answers do not apply in this situation. This is not a duplicate.

From a command prompt on the server, opened as Administrator, I run the **aspnet_regiis** command to encrypt the appSettings section of my web.config using a custom provider.   **Success!** It works. I examine the web.config in a text editor and the section is indeed encrypted.  When I access a setting in that section, it is decrypted transparently.  Perfect.

I want to add another value to the section, and do so on my development PC, copying the new plain-text web.config file up to the server, overwriting the old copy. Then I repeat the command:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "appSettings" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo" -prov "MyCustomEncryptionProvider"
```

and ***this*** is when the error occurs.

Which object already exists? What is the error message referring to?  Did overwriting the old file cause this error? If so, how do I fix it?  I've tried decrypting the *plain-text* version of file that I'd copied up to the server (I get a success! message when I do so) and then re-encrypting, but the "object already exists" error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Between the time of the first successful encryption and the second failed one, my domain identity was removed from a security group with ACL Read permissions on the MachineKeys folder:

\server1\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

My domain identity was added back into that group and everything is working again.